# How do I create a poll on the facebook wall?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a poll on the facebook wall. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the creation of "questions" (aka polls) is not available yet in the API.  If you want you should log a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs and mark it as a wishlist item.

Comment: I founded the official answer from the facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278491632214498

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it isn't possible.
You can only read questions with => "HTTP GET request to the /USER_ID/questions endpoint with the user_questions or friends_questions permissions"
...but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of many pre made poll apps, like this, just search for polls at the top in the apps, then install them on your page http://www.facebook.com/mypoll.page .
Another way would be to make an app that does the job, I have created apps before to add tabs to Facebook, you can put whatever you want on them then like a poll. Im not 100% how to post it to your wall without digging some more, but the example I posted above shows the poll posted on the wall.